# Deleted resources still appear in dashboard all resources widget

Tags: azure

I've deleted several resources and resource groups a week ago, and they still appear in the list of the all resources widget on my dashboard, even after refreshing it.  If I select one of the resources, dhe details page is empty and says "Deleted".  Shouldn't it automatically be removed?  And now, how can I actually refresh things?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Have you contacted Microsoft Support with regards to this question?  Have you verified the behavior on a separate device?

Comment: Do you check use another browser or other PC? It seems a browser cache problem.

Comment: @Walter - Absolutely correct.  Looks to be an issue with browser caching.   a ctrl + f5 updated the widget. I think it is caching the ajax call for that specific widget, because other widgets update fine which through me off.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because troubleshooting like questions are off-topic on this site.